# Remove "Shop" from Woocommerce breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I don't have  a main shop page, only product categories. The Woocommerce breadcrumbs always show a "Shop" trail in the breadcrumbs which I need to remove. In the Woo docs I can only fibd info on how to change tthe "home" slug or delimiter, or how to remove the breadcrumbs entirely. How do I simply remove the "Shop" trail though?

EDIT: I do not want to alter/change the name/link of the "shop" trail but completely remove it!

Comment: No, this person wanted to change the name and url of the "shop" trail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove completely "Shop" from Woocommerce breadcrumbs, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'remove_shop_crumb', 20, 2 );
function remove_shop_crumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        if( $crumb[0] === __('Shop', 'Woocommerce') ) {
            unset($crumbs[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows on the product search result page...actually, there is no "shop" trail but a "product" trail since I have deleted the "shop" page...

Comment: @Lotus In your question you asked to remove "shop" from breadcrumps, and this is what my code does for real *(Note that by default there is no "Product" in breadcrumbs)*… So sorry, but this answer answers your initial question and should be accepted. Now you should ask **a new question** explaining better what do you want with some necessary details and explanations.

Comment: It does not remove it competely from the product search result page(the one that is displayed when using the Woo search widget). It leaves a delimiter on that page bread crumb. And in my case, since the "shop" page is completely deleted, it actually adds the trail "product" instead of shop. This seems to be default behaviour by Woocommerce. You can test this by deleting the shop page and then you will see it on the product search result page.

Comment: Did you see my new question?

Comment: It is important to mention that you have to "reindex" the array after unsetting certain items. If you don't do this the breadcrumb breaks!

Instead of `return $crumbs;` you have to `return array_values($crumbs);`

Comment: @Sebastian No sorry you are wrong… This works just fine as it is.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec at least not for the current woocommerce version. If you take a look at the breadcrumb template you can see that the index is used to decide whether to add another separator or not and also to decide whether the item should be linked or not. Line 31 & 39: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/templates/global/breadcrumb.php

Ex. if you remove the first item with key/index 0 it will start with index 1 instead of 0 which cause problems then.

Comment: @Sebastian I will look at that and I will make an update…

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me, looks like woocommerce takes in consideration the index in the crumbs array.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'remove_shop_crumb', 20, 2);
function remove_shop_crumb($crumbs, $breadcrumb)
{
    $new_crumbs = array();
    foreach ($crumbs as $key => $crumb) {
        if ($crumb[0] !== __('Shop', 'Woocommerce')) {
            $new_crumbs[] = $crumb;
        }
    }
    return $new_crumbs;
}
```

I hope this helps someone
Thanks

Comment: This one works best as it doesn't break the breadcrumbs or leave lots of forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

For full control over the breadcrubs output I would recommend copying the file breadcrumb.php located in --> plugins/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php
Put it at you-theme-folder/woocommerce/global/breadcrumb.php

My default breadcrumbs looked like this: 
"Home » Shop » Home » Category » Subcategory » Product"
Home for some reason appeared twice. Below is the code from breadcrumb.php which shows how I removed the first apparence of "Home" and "Shop"

```
if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

echo $wrap_before;

foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

    echo $before;

    //Every crumb have a $key which starts at 0 for the first crumb. 
    //Here I simply skip out of the loop for the first two crumbs. 
    //You can just echo the $key to see what number you need to remove. 
    if( $key === 0 || $key === 1 ){
        continue;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
    }

    echo $after;

    if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
        echo ' &raquo; ';
    }
}

echo $wrap_after;

}
```

To change urls, just set a new within the anchortag for a given $key or crumb[0] value.
If you only whant this to happen at specific places in your store, just use woocommerce conditional functions such as:

```
if(is_product()){
    if( $key === 0 || $key === 1 ){
       continue;
    }
}
```

Only removes the two first crumbs if at a single product page. See more at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is more simple:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'remove_breadcrumb_home');

function remove_breadcrumb_home( $breadcrumb )
{
    array_shift($breadcrumb);
    return $breadcrumb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me
It changes the JSON yoast seo

Last Tested:  Yoast SEO 16.9 on WordPress 5.8

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links' ,'wpseo_remove_breadcrumb_link', 10 );

function wpseo_remove_breadcrumb_link( $links ){
    // Remove all breadcrumbs that have the text: Shop.
    $new_links = array_filter( $links, function ( $link ) { return $link['text'] !== 'Shop'; } );
 
    // Reset array keys.
    return array_values( $new_links );
}
```